# Maven bundle plugin, what is the difference between <Private-Package> and embedding dependency?

Tags: maven, osgi

[Here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) is the reference on Maven Bundle Plugin. I've read it, and concluded, that if I want to use some other package inside my bundle and I want to keep this as an implementation detail, I don't want to import or export this dependency, than I shall use [Private-Package](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#private-package) instruction. And, there is a possibility of embedding dependencies, which is described [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies). So, my question - isn't it the same, and if not - what is the difference?

Comment: Since you are investigating maven plugins to build OSGi bundles, may I suggest you also look at the maven plugin from Bnd itself? https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin/README.md. We just released version 3.2.

Comment: Ok, thank you for advise - I will keep this idea in mind. But - could you please explain, why it is recommended to use .bnd files instead of having all the build settings in one place, like pom.xml? I see this approach in every plugin from BND team - the same thing with gradle. I really appreciate work of BND team, the tool is great, but it would be good to have an opportunity to work with it smoothly from every build tool without having extra files.

Comment: Well bnd has a native configuration format, the bnd file. So using those directly in every tool, gradle, maven, ant, makes it work smoothly :-) Having to replicate the bnd configuration in the tools native configuration format can create impedance issues, documentation issues and also currency issues when bnd itself is updated to add new configuration but the various mappings to the tool native configuration is not kept up to date.